# How can I attach multiple models to an entity in Garry's Mod?

Tags: lua, entity, garrys-mod

I want to make a scripted entity that looks like the left side of this picture, combining several models together: the equipment rack, computer screen, keyboard, battery, etc.

I want to do this with Lua scripting, not by using Blender to merge all these models together into one.

How can I do this?

[image: Left: several Half-Life 2 models arranged together to create a more complex object. Right: the base model by itself.]

Comment: there, since I think I know exactly what Fako wants to know, and it would be good to have a question answering how to do this, I have rewritten the question. If this was incorrect, Fako can undo it by clicking on "edited ...." and rolling back to the first version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **you have two distinct models** :

- models/machine/machime.mdl
- models/rack/rack.mdl

**You can then create two entities** :

1. The machine entity

   1.1 lua/entities/machine/init.lua

```lua
AddCSLuaFile( "cl_init.lua" )
AddCSLuaFile( "shared.lua" )

include('shared.lua')

function ENT:Initialize()
   self:SetModel("models/machime/machime.mdl")
   self:PhysicsInit(SOLID_VPHYSICS)
   self:SetMoveType(MOVETYPE_VPHYSICS)
   self:SetSolid(SOLID_VPHYSICS)

   local phys = self:GetPhysicsObject()

   if phys:IsValid() then
      phys:Wake()
   end
end
```

1.2 lua/entities/machine/cl_init.lua

```lua
include('shared.lua')

function ENT:Draw()
  self:DrawModel()
end
```

1.3 lua/entities/machine/shared.lua

```lua
ENT.Type = "anim"
ENT.Base = "base_gmodentity"

ENT.AdminOnly   = false
ENT.Spawnable   = true
ENT.PrintName   = "My machine"
ENT.Purpose     = "This is a really good machine"
```

2. The rack entity

   2.1 lua/entities/rack/init.lua

```lua
AddCSLuaFile( "cl_init.lua" )
AddCSLuaFile( "shared.lua" )

include('shared.lua')

function ENT:Initialize()
   self:SetModel("models/rack/rack.mdl")
   self:PhysicsInit(SOLID_VPHYSICS)
   self:SetMoveType(MOVETYPE_VPHYSICS)
   self:SetSolid(SOLID_VPHYSICS)

   local phys = self:GetPhysicsObject()

   if phys:IsValid() then
      phys:Wake()
   end
end
```

2.2 lua/entities/rack/cl_init.lua

```lua
include('shared.lua')

function ENT:Draw()
  self:DrawModel()
end
```

2.3 lua/entities/rack/shared.lua

```lua
ENT.Type = "anim"
ENT.Base = "base_gmodentity"

ENT.AdminOnly   = false
ENT.Spawnable   = true
ENT.PrintName   = "My rack"
ENT.Purpose     = "To rack them all"
```

**Finally to put the rack in the machine** you can use [`ENT:SetParent`](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Entity:SetParent) :

```lua
local machine = ents.Create("machine") -- create a new machine entity
machine:SetPos(THE_POSITION) -- change the position of spawn
machine:Spawn() -- spawn it

local rack = ents.Create("rack") -- create a rack entity
rack:SetParent(machine) -- set the parent to machine
rack:SetLocalPos(THE_LOCAL_POS) -- where the rack is relative to the machine
rack:Spawn() -- spawn it
```

*Note :* In the last part the example spawn *and* put the rack in the machine. You could also use the [`ShouldCollide`](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/GM:ShouldCollide) hook to put the rack in the machine when they'r about to collide !